# How do I recreate these Bouncy hair Physics?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, soft-body

Reference Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqBmxRmI5OM

***How Can I recreate these Hair Physics?***

From what I can tell, the hair can:

Jiggle

Bounce opposite directions (<--- (head) ---->)

^ Kinda Like Anime Physics.

> Reference File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10SZJ1oqHpUndhmQSrd_IFhEescsaYOgp
>
> Includes: Animation Test File / Model (Rig)

If you can post the end file, and give me an replied Tutorial here, on: how to recreate it. That'll be **Really appreciate...!**

Looking forward to reading your responses!

Comment: First guess is using [MikuMikuDance](http://www.geocities.jp/higuchuu4/index_e.htm). There is a [blender mmd_tools addon](https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools). You could either use soft body or clothe sim on a hair mesh to simulate the hair, the top verts are pinned to follow the head, the rest is simulated.

Comment: @sambler, I use the MMD_Tools Addon, I don't want to revert to MMD, I used the addon to create the Reference file. **Can you perform the Softbody / cloth sim on the hair, because whenever I try to use either, the results are awful...**

Comment: If it´s not necessary to work with the same hierarchy than the original MMD, I´d recommend doing the cloth sim on the hair directly.